# How to set class-property and re-use it on another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a class with inputs where I set values trough Class A. How can I access those property-values in Class B?

E.g.

```
namespace Example{
   public class Inputs {
      public string Something { get; set; }
   }
```

Class A:

```
Inputs test = new Inputs();

test.Something = txtSomething.Text;
```

Class B:

```
//How do I access values I declared in class A, or did I do something wrong?
```

Comment: What is class B? Where are you trying to access class A? You just have a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class B{
        public Inputs Test { get; set; }
  }


  var b = new B();
  b.Test = new Inputs();
  b.Test.Something = txtSomething.Text;
```

---

```
  public class B{
        public B(Inputs myB)
        { this.MyB = myB; }

        public Inputs MyB { get; set; }
  }

Inputs test = new Inputs();
test.Something = txtSomething.Text;
 var b = new B(test );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give `B` a copy of `test` in its constructor.

```
public class A
{
    private Inputs _test;

    public A()
    {
        _test = new Inputs();
        new B(_test);
    }
}


public class B
{
    private Inputs _input;

    public B(Inputs input)
    {
        _input= input;
    }
}
```

any changes to `A._test.Somthing` will also show up in `B._input.Somthing`.